# How to concatenate strings in TCL without adding whitespace

Tags: string, tcl

I want to concatenate two strings without any whitespaces between the strings that are being concatenated.
But when I use the commands below, I get strings concatenated with whitespaces added between them. How to concatenate the strings without adding whitespaces?

```
set A "Test"
set B "data"

set C $A$B
```

Current Output :

```
Test       data
```

I need output similar to this :

```
Testdata
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I try that, it works like this:

```
$ tclsh
% set A "Test"
Test
% set B "data"
data
% set C $A$B
Testdata
```

Could it be you have accidentally entered some control character between A and $?

Comment: you are correct. I'm actually reading those variables from a file. And i see that there is a lot of space between them when i tried printing that using puts"$A$B". Is there any command in tcl to cut off the whitespace between them?

Comment: The `string trim` command will remove whitespace. So `set C [string trim $A][string trim $B]` might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Tcl command [join](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/join.htm).

```
% set A "Test"
Test
% set B "data"
data
% join [list $A $B] ""
Testdata
```

Comment: This should not have been voted down, this is the most functional answer to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **append** command

syntax for **append** is

```
append var "," $value 
                        #appends value to variable
```

Without specifying the quotes, the default is **null**

so,

```
  set A "Test"
  set B "data"
  append A $B
  puts "$A"
```

The variable contains "Testdata"